# If two modules are each isomorphic to direct summands of the other, must they be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring. $M,N$ are left $R$-modules such that $M$ is isomorphic to a direct summand of $N$ and $N$ is isomorphic to a direct summand of $M$. Could we get that $M \cong N$?  (This holds if $M,N$ are finitely generated.  I think it also holds if $M,N$ are semisimple.  But I don't have a proof for the general case.)

Comment: Could you write out what you mean by 'direct summand of', mathematically?

Comment: @ChrisCuster For OP's purposes, $M$ is a direct summand of $N$ if there exists an isomorphism $N\cong A\oplus B$ for some $A$ and $B$, where $B\cong M$ as $R$-modules. (This avoids the internal vs. external distinction.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not always true.  Here's the simplest example I know of.  Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, and let $M$ be the set of all bounded sequences of elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, which form an abelian group under pointwise addition.  It is easy to see that $M\cong M\oplus\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]\cong M\oplus\mathbb{Z}^2$.  Much less obviously, [Jeremy Rickard proved on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/227443/75) that $M\not\cong M\oplus \mathbb{Z}$.  Taking $N=M\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, then, $M$ is a direct summand of $N$ and $N$ is a direct summand of $M\oplus\mathbb{Z}^2\cong M$ but $M$ and $N$ are not isomorphic.

There are many other examples of similar phenomena.  For instance, by theorem of Corner, there exists an abelian group $M$ such that $M\cong M^3$ but $M\not\cong M^2$.  Taking $N=M^2$, we then have that $M$ is a direct summand of $N$ and $N$ is a direct summand of $M^3\cong M$, but $M$ and $N$ are not isomorphic.  For references and some general discussion of results like these, see the answers to [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3).

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. Could we get the result under the condition that  $M,N$ are semisimple?

Comment: Yes, because then $M$ and $N$ are direct sums of simple modules and $M$ is a direct summand of $N$ iff each isomorphism class of simple module appears no more times in $M$ than in $N$ (this takes some work to prove).  It then follows by Schroder-Bernstein that $M$ and $N$ have the same number of copies of each simple module.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.